# pointer to string in c

Tags: c, pointers

i did a small program to search a string in another string and placing that sub-string in main string by making it reverse but i am getting segmentation fault while running. please some one help me why i am getting this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "this is my new text";
    char *sstring = "is";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int slen = strlen(sstring);
    char *tstring;
    tstring = str;
    int flag = 0;
    while (len)
    {
        if( *tstring == *sstring){
        int i;
        for( i =0;i < slen; i++){
            if(*(tstring+i) == *(sstring + i))
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag)
    {
        int tlen = slen;
        while(slen-- && (* tstring++ = *sstring + (slen - 1)))
            ;
        tstring = tstring + tlen;
        len = len - tlen;

    }
    len --;
    tstring++;
}
printf("%s",str);
return 0;
```

}

getting error in bellow line

`while(slen-- && (* tstring++ = *sstring + (slen - 1)))`

please someone help

Thanks
Rabi

Comment: Both `tstring` and `sstring` point to string literals which are typically stored in read only memory. You need to put the strings in writable buffers. If the size of the string does not change you have the option of doing `char str[] = "this is my new text";`

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply and in my understanding char *str, char *tstring and "this is my new text" will take stack memory location while executing but how they are allocating memory for readonly memory and writable memory in stack could you let me know or any reference to it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *str = "this is my new text";
char *sstring = "is";
int len = strlen(str);
int slen = strlen(sstring);
char *tstring;
tstring = str;
```

At this point, `tstring` points to a string constant, just as `str` does.

```
    while(slen-- && (* tstring++ = *sstring + (slen - 1)))
```

Here, you try to modify what `tstring` points to. But you can't modify a constant.

Answer (score 0):

sample for fix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str[] = "this is my new text";
    char *sstring = "is";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int slen = strlen(sstring);
    char *tstring;
    int i, flag;

    tstring = str;
    for(i=0; i <= len-slen; ++i){
        int j;
        flag = 1;
        for(j=0; j < slen; ++j){
            if(tstring[j] != sstring[j]){
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag){
            for(j=slen-1;j>=0;--j)
                *tstring++ = sstring[j];
            i += slen-1;
        } else
            ++tstring;
    }
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```